# Modify a string repeatedly in C

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

I want to modify a string like this:—

```
MainString="",            ToUpdate="ABC" -> return# "ABC=1"
MainString="ABC=1",       ToUpdate="ABC" -> return# "ABC=2"
MainString="ABC=2",       ToUpdate="ABC" -> return# "ABC=3"
MainString="ABC=3",       ToUpdate="XYZ" -> return# "ABC=3:XYZ=1"
MainString="ABC=3:XYZ=1", ToUpdate="XYZ" -> return# "ABC=3:XYZ=2"
MainString="ABC=3:XYZ=2", ToUpdate="XYZ" -> return# "ABC=3:XYZ=3"
```

I have the following function:

```
void UpdateString(char *MainString, char ToUpdate[20])
{
    char *pData[50][2];
    char *saveptr1=NULL;
    int i=0,j=0,nIsPresentFlag=0;
    unsigned int CdrCnt=1;
    char workbuf1[200];
    char workbuf[200];


    memset(workbuf,0,200);
    memset(workbuf1,0,200);

    if(strlen(MainString)>0)
    {
        strcat(MainString,":");
    }

    strcpy(workbuf1,MainString);

    pData[i][0]=strtok_r(workbuf1,"=",&saveptr1);
    pData[i][1]=strtok_r(NULL,":",&saveptr1);

    if(pData[i][0]) {i++;pData[i][0]=NULL; pData[i][1]=NULL;}

    while((pData[i][0]=strtok_r(NULL,"=",&saveptr1)))
    {
        pData[i][1]=strtok_r(NULL,":",&saveptr1);
        i++;
    }

    for(j=0;j<i;j++)
        if(strncmp(ToUpdate,pData[j][0],strlen(pData[j][0]))==0)
        {
            CdrCnt=atoi(pData[j][1]);
            CdrCnt+=1;
            sprintf(pData[j][1],"%d",CdrCnt);
            nIsPresentFlag=1;
            break;
        }

    if(nIsPresentFlag==1)
        for(j=0;j<i;j++)
            sprintf(workbuf,"%s%s=%s:",workbuf,pData[j][0],pData[j][1]);
    else
        sprintf(workbuf,"%s%s=%d:",MainString,ToUpdate,1);

    workbuf[strlen(workbuf)-1]='\0';


    memset(MainString,0,200);
    strcpy(MainString,workbuf);

}
```

Curiously, this function is working, but sometimes causing a core dump with segfault.

What is wrong with this code? Any better way I can manage the above task?

==============================================================================

## EDIT 1

String declaration:

```
char MainString[200];
```

The call is like:

```
UpdateString((char*)&MainString,"ABC");
```

Comment: `UpdateString((char*)&MainString,"ABC");` is wrong - call it as `UpdateString(MainString,"ABC");`. &MainString is actually `char **` - casting it will not change that.

Comment: gdb is giving a core dump...

Comment: And you compiled with `-g` so you should be able to get a stack backtrace telling you where the crash occurred — which line in which function...

Comment: @user93353: Ok, let me check that!

Comment: @user93353: strictly, `&MainString` is a `char (*)[200]`, a pointer to an array of 200 characters.  It's value is also the same as `&MainString[0]` and `MainString`, but its type is different.  You're correct that there is a type mismatch; you're not strictly correct on what the mismatched types are.  The cast was added because the compiler (correctly) complained.  @termite_paste: there are occasions when casts are necessary, but this isn't one of them.

Comment: It again crashed.

GDB# 0x0003e684 in UpdateString (MainString=0x2168a0 "ABC=1000:=10:", ToUpdate=0x2acbec "XYZ") at Test.c:59 ...

Line 59# sprintf(workbuf,"%s%s=%s:",workbuf,pData[j][0],pData[j][1]);

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler: So, do I call the function this way: `UpdateString(&MainString,"ABC");`

Comment: @termite_paste, `UpdateString()` expects a `char *` as the first argument. `&MainString`, like Jonathan said, is a `char (*)[200]`. If you called it like: `UpdateString(MainString, "ABC")`, you are passing a `char [200]` to a function that expects a `char *`. So change your function definition from `UpdateString(char *, char [])` to `UpdateString(char [], char [])` and then call it as `UpdateString(MainString, "ABC")`.

Comment: This should require no such change to the parameter list. Leave it the way it is and invoke it as `UpdateString(MainString, "ABC")`. But you *do* need assurance that the caller has properly initialized `MainString` from inception to be a terminated string (i.e. nullchar in the [0] slot from the outset). The caller-side code you present here shows no evidence this i being done.

Comment: @WhozCraig: I used `memset(MainString,0,200);` after `char MainString[200];`... Is this correct, or do I `MainString[0]='\0'`???

Comment: @termite_paste Minus the quoted char (just use `0` , it's the universal char terminator), either will work. It sounds like you have it properly initialized. That being the case, your function is in-fact broken. I'll take a peek if I get the chance. Work really interferes with the SO-sociallife.

Comment: @AnishRam For calling it as `UpdateString(MainString, "ABC")`, you can keep the function signature as `UpdateString(char *, char [])` - there is no type mismatch.

Comment: @user93353, Are you implying that `char []` and `char *` are the same?

Comment: @AnishRam In this case, the `char []` decays into a `char *` - For eg. `puts` is prototyped to take a `char *`. But you can pass a `char s[100]; strcpy(s,"Hello"); puts(s);` Pick up K & R or any basic C book - it can help you with this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Preliminary observation

Given this test code:

```
static void chkit(char *s, char *u)
{
    printf("[%s] && [%s]", s, u);
    UpdateString(s, u);
    printf(" ==> [%s]\n", s);
}

int main(void)
{
    char MainString[200] = "";

    chkit(MainString, "ABC");
    chkit(MainString, "ABC");
    chkit(MainString, "ABC");
    chkit(MainString, "XYZ");
    chkit(MainString, "XYZ");
    chkit(MainString, "XYZ");
    chkit(MainString, "DEF");
    chkit(MainString, "ABC");
    chkit(MainString, "ABC");
    chkit(MainString, "ABC");
    chkit(MainString, "ABC");
    chkit(MainString, "ABC");
    chkit(MainString, "ABC");
    chkit(MainString, "ABC");
    chkit(MainString, "XYZ");
    chkit(MainString, "ABC");
    chkit(MainString, "GHI");
    return 0;
}
```

The output I get is:

```
[] && [ABC] ==> [ABC=1]
[ABC=1] && [ABC] ==> [ABC=2]
[ABC=2] && [ABC] ==> [ABC=3]
[ABC=3] && [XYZ] ==> [ABC=3:XYZ=1]
[ABC=3:XYZ=1] && [XYZ] ==> [ABC=3:XYZ=2]
[ABC=3:XYZ=2] && [XYZ] ==> [ABC=3:XYZ=3]
[ABC=3:XYZ=3] && [DEF] ==> [ABC=3:XYZ=3:DEF=1]
[ABC=3:XYZ=3:DEF=1] && [ABC] ==> [ABC=4:XYZ=3:DEF=1]
[ABC=4:XYZ=3:DEF=1] && [ABC] ==> [ABC=5:XYZ=3:DEF=1]
[ABC=5:XYZ=3:DEF=1] && [ABC] ==> [ABC=6:XYZ=3:DEF=1]
[ABC=6:XYZ=3:DEF=1] && [ABC] ==> [ABC=7:XYZ=3:DEF=1]
[ABC=7:XYZ=3:DEF=1] && [ABC] ==> [ABC=8:XYZ=3:DEF=1]
[ABC=8:XYZ=3:DEF=1] && [ABC] ==> [ABC=9:XYZ=3:DEF=1]
[ABC=9:XYZ=3:DEF=1] && [ABC] ==> [ABC=10:=3:DEF=1]
[ABC=10:=3:DEF=1] && [XYZ] ==> [ABC=10:=3:DEF=1:XYZ=1]
[ABC=10:=3:DEF=1:XYZ=1] && [ABC] ==> [ABC=11:3:DEF=1:XYZ=1]
[ABC=11:3:DEF=1:XYZ=1] && [GHI] ==> [ABC=11:3:DEF=1:XYZ=1:GHI=1]
```

There's clearly a problem when the numbers increase from 1 digit to 2 digits.

#### One problem

In the code:

```
if (nIsPresentFlag == 1)
    for (j = 0; j < i; j++)
        sprintf(workbuf, "%s%s=%s:", workbuf, pData[j][0], pData[j][1]);
```

you are invoking undefined behaviour by writing into `workbuf` and passing it as one of the parameters.  That is simply dangerous.  There's a moderate chance you'll get away with it, but 'get away' is the operative term — there's no guarantee that it will work.

The overwrite problem occurs when you format the new number into insufficient space.

#### Working code

The code below seems to work:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

static void UpdateString(char *MainString, char ToUpdate[20])
{
    char *pData[50][2];
    char *saveptr1 = NULL;
    int   i = 0;
    int   nIsPresentFlag = 0;
    char  workbuf1[200];
    char  workbuf[200];
    char  extra[16];

    if (strlen(MainString) > 0)
        strcat(MainString, ":");

    strcpy(workbuf1, MainString);

    pData[i][0] = strtok_r(workbuf1, "=", &saveptr1);
    pData[i][1] = strtok_r(NULL, ":", &saveptr1);

    if (pData[i][0])
        i++;

    while ((pData[i][0] = strtok_r(NULL, "=", &saveptr1)) != 0)
    {
        pData[i][1] = strtok_r(NULL, ":", &saveptr1);
        i++;
    }

    for (int j = 0; j < i; j++)
    {
        if (strncmp(ToUpdate, pData[j][0], strlen(pData[j][0])) == 0)
        {
            unsigned int CdrCnt = atoi(pData[j][1]);
            CdrCnt += 1;
            pData[j][1] = extra;
            sprintf(pData[j][1], "%u", CdrCnt);
            nIsPresentFlag = 1;
            break;
        }
    }

    if (nIsPresentFlag == 1)
    {
        char *dst = workbuf;
        for (int j = 0; j < i; j++)
        {
            int n = sprintf(dst, "%s=%s:", pData[j][0], pData[j][1]);
            /* Broken if sprintf() returns -1 */
            dst += n;
        }
    }
    else
        sprintf(workbuf, "%s%s=%d:", MainString, ToUpdate, 1);

    workbuf[strlen(workbuf)-1] = '\0';

    strcpy(MainString, workbuf);
}

static void chkit(char *s, char *u)
{
    printf("[%s] && [%s]", s, u);
    UpdateString(s, u);
    printf(" ==> [%s]\n", s);
}

int main(void)
{
    char MainString[200] = "";

    chkit(MainString, "ABC");
    chkit(MainString, "ABC");
    chkit(MainString, "ABC");
    chkit(MainString, "XYZ");
    chkit(MainString, "XYZ");
    chkit(MainString, "XYZ");
    chkit(MainString, "DEF");
    chkit(MainString, "ABC");
    chkit(MainString, "ABC");
    chkit(MainString, "ABC");
    chkit(MainString, "ABC");
    chkit(MainString, "ABC");
    chkit(MainString, "ABC");
    chkit(MainString, "ABC");
    chkit(MainString, "XYZ");
    chkit(MainString, "ABC");
    chkit(MainString, "GHI");
    chkit(MainString, "PQRSTU");
    chkit(MainString, "I");
    chkit(MainString, "I");
    chkit(MainString, "I");
    chkit(MainString, "PQRSTU");

    return 0;
}
```

It leaves out the `memset()` operations; a null terminated string can be copied over arbitrary data and as long as you don't go looking beyond the null terminator, you won't have any problems. The variable `extra` is used to store the new number; it avoids problems when the number changes from N to N+1 digits.  The function `sprintf()` returns the number of characters it wrote; that is used to add the data to the work buffer safely.

#### Example output

```
[] && [ABC] ==> [ABC=1]
[ABC=1] && [ABC] ==> [ABC=2]
[ABC=2] && [ABC] ==> [ABC=3]
[ABC=3] && [XYZ] ==> [ABC=3:XYZ=1]
[ABC=3:XYZ=1] && [XYZ] ==> [ABC=3:XYZ=2]
[ABC=3:XYZ=2] && [XYZ] ==> [ABC=3:XYZ=3]
[ABC=3:XYZ=3] && [DEF] ==> [ABC=3:XYZ=3:DEF=1]
[ABC=3:XYZ=3:DEF=1] && [ABC] ==> [ABC=4:XYZ=3:DEF=1]
[ABC=4:XYZ=3:DEF=1] && [ABC] ==> [ABC=5:XYZ=3:DEF=1]
[ABC=5:XYZ=3:DEF=1] && [ABC] ==> [ABC=6:XYZ=3:DEF=1]
[ABC=6:XYZ=3:DEF=1] && [ABC] ==> [ABC=7:XYZ=3:DEF=1]
[ABC=7:XYZ=3:DEF=1] && [ABC] ==> [ABC=8:XYZ=3:DEF=1]
[ABC=8:XYZ=3:DEF=1] && [ABC] ==> [ABC=9:XYZ=3:DEF=1]
[ABC=9:XYZ=3:DEF=1] && [ABC] ==> [ABC=10:XYZ=3:DEF=1]
[ABC=10:XYZ=3:DEF=1] && [XYZ] ==> [ABC=10:XYZ=4:DEF=1]
[ABC=10:XYZ=4:DEF=1] && [ABC] ==> [ABC=11:XYZ=4:DEF=1]
[ABC=11:XYZ=4:DEF=1] && [GHI] ==> [ABC=11:XYZ=4:DEF=1:GHI=1]
[ABC=11:XYZ=4:DEF=1:GHI=1] && [PQRSTU] ==> [ABC=11:XYZ=4:DEF=1:GHI=1:PQRSTU=1]
[ABC=11:XYZ=4:DEF=1:GHI=1:PQRSTU=1] && [I] ==> [ABC=11:XYZ=4:DEF=1:GHI=1:PQRSTU=1:I=1]
[ABC=11:XYZ=4:DEF=1:GHI=1:PQRSTU=1:I=1] && [I] ==> [ABC=11:XYZ=4:DEF=1:GHI=1:PQRSTU=1:I=2]
[ABC=11:XYZ=4:DEF=1:GHI=1:PQRSTU=1:I=2] && [I] ==> [ABC=11:XYZ=4:DEF=1:GHI=1:PQRSTU=1:I=3]
[ABC=11:XYZ=4:DEF=1:GHI=1:PQRSTU=1:I=3] && [PQRSTU] ==> [ABC=11:XYZ=4:DEF=1:GHI=1:PQRSTU=2:I=3]
```

I did some basic checking with `valgrind` (and added some dynamic memory allocation) and it came up with a clean bill of health.

Note the style of diagnostic printing.  It shows the inputs and the output, which is helpful.  And it encloses strings in a distinctive marker (here `[]`) so that stray spaces etc can be spotted more easily.

Comment: +1 (and I'd do it again if I could). *Thank You* for taking the time to do this and save the sanity of the rest of us =P.

Comment: Thanks @Jonathan Leffler!!! It works greats!!!
`PARTNER1=8:PARTNER2=42:PARTNER3=2498; 
PARTNER3=1167:PARTNER1=15:PARTNER2=1220; 
PARTNER2=425:PARTNER3=3:PARTNER1=1673; 
PARTNER2=1834:PARTNER3=1:PARTNER1=554; 
PARTNER2=1:PARTNER1=1:PARTNER3=1
PARTNER1=151:PARTNER2=732:PARTNER3=1
`